# Исключающее регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

К сожалению, не силен в регулярных выражениях. Поэтому прошу помощи в выражении, которое будет выполнять поиск символов `\n` только за пределами, допустим `{...}`, т.е если есть блок текста в пределах фигурных скобок, в них не производить поиск символа переноса строки, только ЗА пределами:

```
...ищем...{...нет...}...снова ищем..{...ишем?...{...нет...}...ищем...
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я бы предложил решить таким способом: найти сначала все фигурные скобочки, в том числе и вложенные, ну а все, что не попадет под это регулярное выражение найдет нужные Вам \n.  
В [Хабрапосте][1] описано подобное регулярное выражение, только вместо {} ищутся ().  
[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/56765/

Comment: почему-то не подумал об этом, приму к сведению, спасибо, но всё равно надеюсь на готовую регулярку=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу рабочий пример для PHP демонстрирующий мой коммент к вопросу.
Не знаю, есть ли в C# рекурсивные выражения, но в PHP они работают.
В данном примере в строке символы `a` **внутри** скобок заменяются символом `c` (на реальных строках это может быть непечатный символ вроде BELL итп).
Потом все оставшиеся `a` заменяются на `X`, а `c` обратно на `a`.
То есть в соответствии с вопросом аналогия такая:
`\n = a ; CHR(8) = c ; <BR/> = X`

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8;");
$re='/\{(?>[^}{]+|(?R))+\}/';
$s= <<< HEREDOC
bab{ab{bab}}bab{{{{{ab}}}}}{aba
HEREDOC;
function clb($match){
    return str_replace("a", "c", $match[0]);
};
$result=preg_replace_callback($re, clb, $s);
$result=str_replace("a", "X", $result);
$result=str_replace("c", "a", $result);
echo '<pre>'.$result."</pre>";
?>
```

Результат. Как видим все `a` вне скобок заменены на `X`

```
bXb{ab{bab}}bXb{{{{{ab}}}}}{XbX
```

---

Извините за некроправку, что-то вспомнился этот вопрос.
Сделать это можно так, без лишних замен:

```
$re='/\\n|(?P<rec>\{(?>[^}{]+|(?P>rec))+\})/';
function clb($match){
    if ($match["rec"]) return $match["rec"];
    return "<br/>";
};
$result=preg_replace_callback($re, "clb", $text);
```

В общем виде это выглядит так:

```
$re="/expression1|(?P<name>expression2)/";
function callback($arr) {
    if ($arr["name"]) return $arr["name"];
    return $replace; // здесь то, чем нужно заменить первое выражение
};
```

Сейчас я сам удивляюсь насколько это просто оказывается, но на момент написания ответа все казалось гораздо сложнее в замене вне регулярного выражения.

Comment: почему-то я не подумал пойти таким путём с повторной заменой символов обратно, спасибо за идею

Comment: сколько ни пытался браться за изучение регулярок, они всё равно выглядят для меня как нечто невразумительное=)

ещё раз спасибо!